# How to implement a lazy loading recyclerView adapter like realm recyclerView adapter using kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, realm, kotlin

I need to implement a recyclerView that shows my queries on Parse, so I've done it:

```
 private class Pagination extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener{

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = manager.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = manager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItemPosition = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();


        if (!isLoading && !isLastPage) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                    && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                    && totalItemCount >= PAGINATION) {
                isLoading = true;

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadData();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it works well. But some months ago I've used realm recyclerView adapter that works without pagination (and it works very well because I've 50k items to show) and I want to make an adapter like this. I've also use Kotlin and I've seen the concept of a lazy variable:

```
val lazyValue: String by lazy {
println("computed!")
"Hello"
}
```

but I don't know how to use it to make adapter for this reason: now when I do a query to parse it's something like this:

```
 val dishes = ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>("Books").setSkip(index).setLimit(pagination)

 dishes.findInBackground { objects, e -> e?.let { listener?.onPaginationError(e.message)  } ?:run { createNewDish(objects,listener,false)  } }
```

and how it works when I use a lazy approach? I need to download all items or I need also to paginate?

Comment: What exactly you want to use lazy for?

Comment: @chandil03 waiting the List<Object> that arrives from Parse, they could be 100/1000 etc

Comment: Lazy function is not used for this case. Lazy functions are used when you want to load resource on your first method call, not on initialization of variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I've used realm recyclerView adapter that works without pagination (and it works very well because I've 50k items to show) and I want to make an adapter like this.*

Actually this is magic of Realm, not it's adapter. And you cant get same taste, because Realm's lazy loading architecture will be super fast than others like server-side pagination. Sorry you cant mimic it.

*I need to download all items or I need also to paginate?*

If the server-side data source cant able to handle pagination request, you have to load all items first, then query it on client-side and let the adapter show items on recyclerview

*how it works when I use a lazy approach?*

What i understand is from that, you want to combine kotlin's lazy and pagination ?

Already an adapter needs a data set(maybe items from 10 to 20 from a data source) to show when needed. So i can't see any appropriate usage for kotlin's lazy.